# Prove $\max f(x) = -\min -f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I prove :

$$\max f(x)= - \min -f(x)$$
I am trying to prove this, and have tried to use my book but I am stuck.

Comment: did u used definitions?

Comment: If $f(x) \leq \alpha$ for all $x$, then $-f(x) \geq -\alpha$ for all $x$. Therefore $\max f = \min -f$.

Comment: It should state: max f(x) = - min -f(x), I didn´t find it :/

Comment: Sorry, my fault: $\max f = -\min (-f)$, of course ;-)

Comment: It really does follow almost immediately from the fact that $a\leq b$ if and only if $-b \leq -a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\subset\mathbb R$ have a maximum; i.e. some
$m\in A$ exists such that $a\leq m$ for each $a\in A$.

If $-A$ denotes the set $\left\{ -a\mid a\in A\right\} $ then $-m\in-A$
and $-m\leq-a$ is true for each $a\in A$.

This tells us that $-m$ is a minimum
of $-A$.

Denoting $m=\max A$ and $-m=\min\left(-A\right)$ we have: $$\max A=m=-\left(-m\right)=-\min\left(-A\right)$$